# What could be causing my VM to have video and audio difficulties?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, audio, video, virtual-machine

I have bought a new computer, and although I was informed that it was not tested for Linux I bought it anyway. Linux works fine, but there is a problem I have come across when using Virtualbox VMs.

Audio and video are sometimes distorted (usually by going much faster), but sometimes not. On the host, the only similar issue is that audio very rarely has an echo of the previous second. Apart from that, there are no issues.

Are there any major settings that I can play with to see if I can solve these issues?

Comment: Did you install the VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest OS?

Comment: Yes, it is installed and other features like shared folders work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you install in the virtual machine the "Guest Additions"?

Definition of GA in VirtualBox FAQ: "Guest Additions are designed to be installed inside a virtual machine after the guest operating system has been installed. They consist of device drivers and system applications that optimize the guest operating system for better performance and usability"

To install the "Guest Additions" follow this VirtualBox HowTo "[Installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html)".